# Cannot edit any content Panes in Panopoly installation, getting JS error

Tags: panels, distributions

When I try editing any pane on my site, I get this:

[image]

The following error is in my Web Inspector console:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('.panopoly-textfield-autosubmit, .panopoly-textarea-autosubmit', context)
>         .once('ctools-auto-submit')')
>
> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("select.ctools-master-dependent")
>           .once('ctools-dependent')')
>   `

I've tried changing Jquery Update settings, updating Panopoly to the newest version (along with the modules). No luck.

Comment: What's the error shown in JavaScript console of your browser? Hit F12 and reload page. Chrome can do it out of the box, Firefox requires Firebug, other browsers - can't tell.

Comment: Hi Molot, it's what I pasted in my question (starts with "TypeError").

Comment: Oh, sorry, failed to spot it. Are you using jQuery Update module? Is jQuery version set compatible with all modules' requirements?

Comment: Yes I am. I've just updated the module itself, and the jQuery version is set to 1.7. (That's what works with Panopoly at least) I don't understand why it suddenly starts to happen - we finished the site in June and now our customer is suddenly having this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a such problem with the module jquery_update when we used a library upper jQuery1.7 . Try use different jQuery versions for User interface and the Admin interface. And do not mix them.

Comment: Hi, My jQuery update (/config/development/jquery_update) configuration screen looks like this http://i.imgur.com/x3u6mkf.png shouldn't I be able to select different versions here?

Comment: I wanted to say that it is the main issue. It is the panels issue. Time to time I have a such issue. So I try to use the standard jQuery library and related old libraries. If I need new features. I inject a new library like jq17 making some hacks.

Comment: OK, I was just wondering how to use a different jQuery version for frontend/admin.

Comment: I fixed it by using a CDN inside jQuery settings. Thanks for the pointer. Probably something to do with caching of JS files or similar? Or wrong version perhaps?